# Keyboard in Android physical device isn’t always hidden while using Appium

Tags: android, mobile, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

When I want to hide the keyboard, (because if I don't hide it when I click into a button under keyboard a number from keyboard is pressed instead of the confirm button for example) some times it's hidden ok by the command `driver.hidekeyboard();` and other times it's hidden automatically.

Other times it tells me

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Soft keyboard not present, cannot hide keyboard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use adb command to check whether keyboard has popped up or not

```
adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown
```

Output : `mShowRequested=true mShowExplicitlyRequested=false mShowForced=false mInputShown=true`

if `mInputShown=true` then yes software keyboard has popped up.
Then use `driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);`

PS:  Please do not use `driver.navigate().back()` as its behavior may not be same on all devices.

Comment: After tapping this : Emnas-Mac:~ Emna$ adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown 
I got the following output.
  mShowRequested=false mShowExplicitlyRequested=false mShowForced=false mInputShown=false

So shall i put driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK); in all my scripts that i want to use keyboard?

Comment: if mInputShown=false then you dont need to call driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);

Comment: The problem that the keyoboard appears randomly and in the same screen i have 3 fields that i have to use sendkeys("");
No stability

Comment: Okay , then for synchronization between your script and application , put some sleep before checking keyboard presence on the screen , if present then press AndroidKeyCode.BACK else execute next command

Comment: I have the following problem also : i don't know why keyboard isn't working well sometimes: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989966/in-appium-sendkeys-didnt-work-as-expected-it-sends-more-than-i-give-to-it

Comment: try changing your Auto-Correction setting from Language & Input Setting

Comment: Even if is already OFF the problem is the Same, Can the implicit wait : wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); be the reason for that ?

Comment: No i dont think so. One workaround you can try is after sendkeys get text from from EditText , verify if additional char is added or not then clear EditText then sendkeys("1")

Comment: I also faced this issue. But after turning off auto-correction feature of Keyboard app, issue was resolved. With Appium i dont think there is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Faced a similar problem trying to work on emulator and real time devices. One had the keyboard displayed and another didn't. So the `driver.hideKeyboard();` used to fail for the latter. Just made sure that the keyboard would appear in both the cases and then hidden.

```
driver.getKeyboard();
driver.hideKeyboard();
```

This works fine for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Same problem, driver.getKeyboard();
driver.hideKeyboard(); didn't solve my problem !

Answer (score 2):

@Emna After inputting both field if hidekeyboard doesnt works try. `driver.navigate().back();` or wrap it as

```
public void clickDeviceBackButton(){
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
```

and call `clickDeviceBackButton()` in your testcase

Comment: Try to find AS tatic Text element on the page and .click() there. That dismisses the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Try to find a Static Text/link element on the page and .click() there. That dismisses the keyboard .