# In Appium Sendkeys didn't work as expected, it sends more than i give to it

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, sendkeys

I'm using Appium to write test cases of an Android application, when i tap the following code

```
 public void EnterQuantity() {
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys("1"); 
            }
```

I get 11 in Quantity field instead of 1.
How can i reduce the speed of writing in order to be sure that only the number i gave is written not doubled.

Comment: Please post your appium logs when it tries to execute sendkeys..

Comment: I put is as an answer to that question, but the problem the quantity in log is getting 11 as value not 1.

Comment: try to put some wait command before entering text and also clear the text in the text box.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Auto-Correction setting from Language & Input Setting in android Device manually

Comment: No the problem isn't coming from there, because Auto-correction is OFF

Answer (score 1):

@Emna I beleieve it calls the `EnterQuantity()` twice . try to add click element(eg. submit button) inside this function to narrow down the root cause

Comment: i don't think so, because when i enter a big number as if 2780 it will be written as if 227800 or 27800 or other combination with more than 4 digits. but i had never 27802780

Comment: @Emna got that. But can u try clicking or any button within the functin after giving send keys?

Comment: This is already what i am doing for exemple i enter price & quantity then click into buy order, Then i go to the list of orders i saw that this order has the price and quantity with the added effect 11 instead of 1 and 27800 instead of 2780 or any other combination. This scenario isn't hapening all the time. But let's say 80%

Comment: Then its better to declare the long xpath as an element and click on that element instead of finding and sendingkeys at the same stretch  //code WebElement xyz=wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]"));   xyz.sendKeys("1");

Comment: This should be a good solution because my xpath is too large, i will try it.

Comment: Yes please. there might be a log between finding a long hierarachy and sending input at the same time @Emna

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101759/discussion-between-emna-and-karthick23).