# Soft keyboard not present, cannot hide keyboard - Appium android

Tags: android, testing, selenium-webdriver, keyboard, appium

I am getting following exception:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Soft keyboard not present, cannot hide keyboard) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 368 milliseconds
```

I am using **driver.hideKeyboard()** to hide soft input keyboard that is open on the screen.
How to ensure that keyboard is open before hiding it? OR any other workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use adb command to check whether keyboard has popped up or not

```
adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown 
Output : mShowRequested=true mShowExplicitlyRequested=false mShowForced=false mInputShown=true
```

if `mInputShown=true` then yes software keyboard has popped up. Then use `driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);`

**One way to do using java is**

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown");
        BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String outputText = "";

           while ((outputText = in.readLine()) != null) {

               if(!outputText.trim().equals("")){
                        String keyboardProperties[]=outputText.split(" ");
                        String keyValue[]=keyboardProperties[keyboardProperties.length-1].split("=");

                        String softkeyboardpresenseValue=keyValue[keyValue.length-1];
                        if(softkeyboardpresenseValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                                isKeyboardPresent=false;
                        }else{
                                isKeyboardPresent=true;
                        }
               }
           }
           in.close();
```

PS: Please do not use `driver.navigate().back()` as its behavior may not be same on all devices.

Answer (score 7):

I also get this error, i correct it by using the following code in the setUp method :

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```

You can check answers here : 
[Keyboard in Android physical device isn’t always hidden while using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942654/keyboard-in-android-physical-device-isn-t-always-hidden-while-using-appium/34985455#34985455)

Comment: thanks.after this I don't need to hide keyboard anywhere?

Comment: Yes in that case you have to go to settings in your phone you will see that default keyboard is set to appium, so that no keyboard is needed anymore. This is the better solution i tried a lot.

Comment: thanks again ! I will check it and mark it as answer if works