# UI Element gets hidden by keypad in emulator

Tags: appium, android-softkeyboard

Using Appium, when I launched the app then firstly splash screen appeared then login screen with a keypad. Forgot password button gets hidden by keypad. In this case, Appium is not able to locate forgot password. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8zu1.png).

How can I handle this type of problem?

I have also used the code `driver.hideKeyboard();`, then I get the error in the console as

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing 
the command. (Original error: Soft keyboard not present, cannot hide keyboard) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stack trace information)
Command duration or timeout: 118 milliseconds
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030794/soft-keyboard-not-present-cannot-hide-keyboard-appium-android/35031010#35031010 link

Comment: @ShekharSwami : flagged this duplicate for the same link

Comment: @nullpointer context is different but solution is same . :)

Comment: @Santosh please comment and close your question if your query is resolved.