# Keyboard enable exception on mac

Tags: macos, appium

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
    Could not locate keyboard. (WARNING: The server did not provide any
    stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 23.96 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time:
    '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host: 'QAs-iMac.local', ip:
    '192.168.0.128', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version:
    '10.11.4', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
    [{app=/Users/qa/Desktop/QA Team /pankaj/mac/Boku-1.ipa,
    appPackage=com.boku, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
    appWaitActivity=ui.activities.TutorialActivity,
    databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=iPhone 6, fullReset=true,
    platform=MAC, appActivity=ui.activities.SplashActivity,
    showIOSLog=true, appium-version=1.5.1,
    desired={app=/Users/qa/Desktop/QA Team /pankaj/mac/Boku-1.ipa,
    appPackage=com.boku, appActivity=ui.activities.SplashActivity,
    showIOSLog=true, appium-version=1.5.1, platformVersion=9.3.1,
    appWaitActivity=ui.activities.TutorialActivity, platformName=iOS,
    udid=a87a03d1680a6cfd142829db9b01da43019b278f, deviceName=iPhone 6,
    fullReset=true}, platformVersion=9.3.1, webStorageEnabled=false,
    locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true,
    javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=iOS,
    udid=a87a03d1680a6cfd142829db9b01da43019b278f}] Session ID:
    89125084-e649-40f1-ba95-a738ba417521  at
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
    Method)  at
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
    at Boku.Bokumain.main(Bokumain.java:188)
```

I am facing this issue for sendkeys().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030794/soft-keyboard-not-present-cannot-hide-keyboard-appium-android/35036615#35036615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hide keboard by this way :

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodekeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetkeyboard", true);
```

Comment: hello Emna ,,,great this also works for me ..But i have one more problem

Comment: I want to handle system generated alerts to allow contacts,camera and loctaion in real devices

Comment: Ask it in a separate question, so this one is about keyboard ;)

Comment: I want to handle system generated alerts to allow location ,camera and contacts in ios devices even i used (autoAcceptAlert,true) but it wont work